# Getting radio buttons labels on same line as radio button with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.1
Bootstrap
Bootstrap_forms

I would like to see the label on the same line as the radio button. I tried this:

```
<%= f.form_group do %>
  <%= f.radio_button :role, 'member', :checked => true %>
  <%= f.label :role, 'Non-Candidate / Non-Staff', :style => "display:inline" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :role, 'candidate' %>
  <%= f.label :role, 'Candidate', :style => "display:inline" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :role, 'campaign_staff' %>
  <%= f.label :role, 'Campaign Staff', :style => "display:inline"  %>
<% end %>
```

But it's not working. The label is on the next line for each. Any ideas?

Comment: You can simply put this `<%= f.label :role, 'Non-Candidate / Non-Staff', :style => "display:inline" %>` beside of this `<%= f.radio_button :role, 'member', :checked => true %>`.We always do like that.It works.

Comment: Forgot to say tables.

Comment: I don't understand. This is the same code

Comment: Yes.that's the same code.But you have to do it in that way which i provided in my answer.

Comment: Please try my answer and you would get to know what is the trick i used.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code snippet.  Could it be a space issue where it's going to the next line because there isn't room on the current line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tables and by simply place the `label` code i.e, `<%= f.label :role, 'Non-Candidate / Non-Staff', :style => "display:inline" %>` beside of the `radio_button` code i.e,`<%= f.radio_button :role, 'member', :checked => true %>` and placing them in between `<td></td> tags`.Same applies for the remaining.

```
<%= f.form_group do %>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><%= f.radio_button :role, 'member', :checked => true %><%= f.label :role, 'Non-Candidate / Non-Staff', :style => "display:inline" %></td>

  <td><%= f.radio_button :role, 'candidate' %><%= f.label :role, 'Candidate', :style => "display:inline" %></td>

  <td><%= f.radio_button :role, 'campaign_staff' %><%= f.label :role, 'Campaign Staff', :style => "display:inline"  %></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<% end %>
```

Here is our working snippet code

```
<tr>
<td><%= "Employee Type" %></td>
<td><%= radio_button 'employee', 'employee_type', "employee" %><%= "Employee" %></td>
<td><%= radio_button 'employee', 'employee_type', "retainer" %><%= "Retainer" %></td>
<td><%= radio_button 'employee', 'employee_type', "doctor" %><%= "Doctor" %></td>
</tr>
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: This does not work because I'm using the bootstrap styles, and the bootstrap-forms gem. See my question. In order for this to work, I would need multiple cells for each table row. Using the code you suggested still places the label under the button

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper Can you post screenshot of that?